# Moq setup method failing on callback

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

My unit test is failing on setup method

```
var myMock = new Mock<IMyInterface<IImportLine>>();
        myMock.Setup(m => m.StartExecution(It.IsAny<Func<Stream, IMyInterface<IImportLine>, bool>>(), null))
                     .Callback<Func<Stream, IMyInterface<IImportLine>, bool>>(action => action(null, new IMyInterface<IImportLine>()));
```

IMyInterface looks like below

```
public interface IImportTransport<T> where T : IImportLine
{
    void StartExecution(Func<Stream, ImportOperation<T>, bool> processor, string id = null);
}
```

The error message is **System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (Func3,String) cannot invoke callback with parameters (Func3).**

How do we fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an argument to your callback that corresponds to the `id` parameter (even though you know it'll be null).

```
myMock.Setup(m => m.StartExecution(It.IsAny<Func<Stream, IImportTransport<IImportLine>, bool>>(), null))
    .Callback<Func<Stream, IImportTransport<IImportLine>, bool>, string>(
        (action, id) => action(null, new ImportOperation<IImportLine>()));
```

Since you aren't using that parameter, you can use a *discard* if you like.

```
myMock.Setup(m => m.StartExecution(It.IsAny<Func<Stream, IImportTransport<IImportLine>, bool>>(), null))
    .Callback<Func<Stream, IImportTransport<IImportLine>, bool>, string>(
        (action, _) => action(null, new ImportOperation<IImportLine>()));
```

Comment: Delegate 'Action<Func<Stream, IImportTransport<IImportLine>, bool>>' does not take 2 arguments

Comment: I fixed the signature to address that issue.